# What does it mean that GraphQL is a communication pattern?

Tags: graphql

On this [page of the GraphQL docs](https://graphql.org/code/) it mentions that GraphQL is a communication pattern. What is meant by that?

Is it because GraphQL is another abstraction layer that sits between clients and your API/DB?

Comment: The core functionality of GraphQL is to define a schema definition, with types, queries, mutations and subscriptions, through which a client can communicate with the backend server. The persistency of the data itself isn't the responsibility of GraphQL. So indeed, it's more or less as you quoted a layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they are trying to say is that there are many compliant implementations of GraphQL making it more of a protocol or communication pattern than a single library. Akin to REST or GRPC, there are many implementations that can communicate.